# How to access my localhost tomcat webapp from Internet

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, portforwarding

I have setup my webapp in server's tomcat, so that localhost:8080/{webappName} works fine.

Since I am using AWS service, I have also have the security group with http access to public (0.0.0.0/0).

However I tried typing in http://{public DNS.com}:8080/{webappName} which will fail; trying directly http://{public DNS.com} will show the same content as localhost:80

I also tried editing the tomcat's conf/server.html and change the line:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

I changed the port="8080" to port="80"

but this doesn't work either.

And then I run out of solutions - I prefer not to use the 3rd party tools to do so.

My server is a windows server running on amazon. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Check your error logs to see if there is any output on startup, maybe your application is failing? Also I am not familiar with AWS but maybe it takes a bit for dns to propagate since it is not local?

Comment: @Dan if anything happened in the deployment or startup, I think I won't be able to see localhost:8080/{webappName}, but in fact this is working.

Comment: Is anything listening on port 80 on that machine? For AWS security groups, you typically have to allow anything you want specifically *in* to the box. What does your security group look like?

Comment: did u restart tomcat after changing the port. Check on the AWS machine locally...

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz 80 (HTTP) 0.0.0.0/0 and 8080 (HTTP*) 0.0.0.0/0 which seems allows anything from outside to this port right?

Comment: @sanket yes I restarted but nothing different..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view something on port 8080 you need to open that port on the Instance's Security Group.

http://{public DNS.com}:8080/{webappName} needs port 8080 opened.

Comment: can I direct port 80 to 8080 instead of opening 8080?

Comment: Well it's certainly possible.

Answer (score 0):

turned out I need to turn off my servers Windows Firewall! After that I can access the http://{public DNS.com}/{webappName}